# Paho MQTT Javascript client version 1.1.0 problems connecting

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, paho

I'm having trouble connecting to my Mosquitto broker from the Paho MQTT Javascript client version 1.1.0. I was previously using version 1.0.1, but I decided to change, because I need to use wildcards, which I think they are not supported in version 1.0.1, because they don't work.

To connect in version 1.0.1 I was doing this:

```
host=192.168.1.42
port=9873
id="whatever"
mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host,port,id);
```

In version 1.1.0, this way of connecting doesn't work. I saw an explanation [here](https://pi3g.com/2019/05/17/correct-way-to-instantiate-paho-client-in-javascript-for-wss-secure-websocket/) and I tried it like this:

```
mqtt = new Paho.Client("wss://192.168.1.42/mqtt",id);
```

This results in an error saying that Firefox cannot establish a connection to wss://192.168.1.42/mqtt.

What is the right way of connecting using version 1.1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcard subscriptions will work at any version of the Paho Javascript client. But anyway.

As stated in the [docs](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/jsdoc/Paho.MQTT.Client.html), the Client constructor `host` field can be one of the following:

> the address of the messaging server, as a fully qualified WebSocket URI, as a DNS name or dotted decimal IP address.

You appear to be using a none standard port (9873 vs 443) for your WebSocket listener, so you are going to need to include the port number in the URI.

```
mqtt = new Paho.Client("wss://192.168.1.42:9873/mqtt",id);
```

Comment: I've managed to connect using that, thank you. However, the client disconnects almost inmediately. On the broker, a socket error is logged for that client. Could it be some wrong options settings for the connection? I'm going to edit my question including that.

Comment: That probably should be a separate question, but it is most likely because you have a fixed client id, that won't work in a web world. Every browser that opens the page needs a unique client id

Comment: The client id is unique, I'm using a php session id for that

Comment: OK, the failure to connect should still be a separate question. This answer is the solution to the question you asked.